# Actionscript 3 - How to access integer variable in main timeline from inside MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

First, sorry if my english is bad and I'm new to Actionscript 3.
I have a movieclip, I give it an instance name "symbol1" which include a code inside it, like this :

```
var a: int = 2;
var b: int = 3;
var total: int = a + b;
```

How can I access the "total" integer variable inside that movieclip in the main timeline? I try to trace it but the result is 0. In the main timeline I wrote this code :

```
trace(symbol1.total);
```

I appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: On which frame of symbol1 you have written this code and how many frames does it have? Also,on which frame of the main time line are you trying to access it? Please provide more details. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Gurtej Singh for reply. I wrote only on first frame inside the movieclip also the same as on main timeline. I try to access it on first frame of the main timeline

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're accessing the variable total correctly, otherwise I would expect it to cause an error (you can test this by trying to run `trace(symbol1.variableNameThatDoesntExist)`). The issue might be that the value isn't being updated

Comment: Why does the MovieClip need to hold variables? Its just a`DisplayObject`, a container for visual elements. Difference between MClip and Sprite is that MClip has a timeline so its like a mini-stage (travel through its frames etc) but Sprite is a single-frame container for static visuals.. Also are you telling me when there is 1000 items in a future project you are okay with clicking 1000 times into different MCs just to adjust variables or to find the problem bug code in one of these? I think really you want one Class for your code and then `addChild` the Class into some MovieClip or Sprite

Comment: Jezzamon : thanks for reply. how do I update the value?
VC.One : also thanks for reply. could you tell me how to make one Class for multiple MovieClips?
to all : actually, I've made 6 games. each game is in the MovieClip including the game functions, times, scores, variables, etc. I want the total score of each game summed outside each MoviClips, which is in the main timeline. is there a solution to that problem? Thanks

Comment: @Jezzamon I'm afraid it wouldn't, because `MovieClip` is `dynamic`. I tried to explain it in my answer.

Comment: @null I was talking about it throwing an runtime error, I should've specified

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is the [order of execution of frames](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/orderofoperations/#FrameExecution). The parent is executed first.

The value is `0` and not `undefined` because the property does indeed exist since the creation of the object which happens in a previous separate step.

You should be able to verify that by stepping through your code with the debugger.

> I've made 6 games. each game is in the MovieClip including the game functions, times, scores, variables, etc. I want the total score of each game summed outside each MoviClips, which is in the main timeline. is there a solution to that problem?

This makes your timing problem even more apparent.
You arrive at a frame, which contains a game and you immediately want to access the total score of it. It should be obvious that the game first has to be played in order to obtain a score from it.

Asking a newborn baby what his favourite moment in the first 60 years of his live *was* doesn't make much sense.

You have to notify the main timeline that the game was finished. The best way to do this is to dispatch an `Event` from the game. Frames are totally unnecessary.

Your code could look something like this:

```
var game:Game = new Tetris();
addChild(game);
game.addEventListener(GameEvent.FINISH, onFinish);

function onFinish(e:GameEvent):void
{
    trace("finished game with score " + game.score);
}
```

If you want to update the exterior score sum while the game is running (to immediately reflect any change in the score, not just when the game is finished), your best bet is to create a `ScoreModel` for the score which you pass to the game, the `Game`. The `Game` modifies the `ScoreModel`, which in turn causes it to dispatch `Event`s:

```
var score:ScoreModel = new ScoreModel();
var game:Game = new Tetris(score);
addChild(game);

score.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onScoreChange);

function onScoreChange(e:Event):void
{
    trace("score changed to " + score);
}
```

Both examples are "what your code could look like"-type of examples. There are many questions about how to dispatch events that explain how to do this in more detail.

---

Something that came up in the comments from @Jezzamon:

> I'm pretty sure you're accessing the variable total correctly, otherwise I would expect it to cause an error (you can test this by trying to run trace(symbol1.variableNameThatDoesntExist)).

No, there cannot be an error for accessing a variable as seen in the question. The reason for that is that the property is accessed on a `MovieClip` object, which is a `dynamic` class. As such, the compiler doesn't know if accessing a particular property is valid, because that can change at runtime. And because nothing else relies on the value to be valid, there isn't a runtime error either.

Here's some example code to illustrate this:

```
trace("toString: " + {}.toString); //toString: function Function() {}
trace("bananas: " + {}.bananas); //bananas: undefined
```

This is one of the reasons why using `MovieClip` can be a bad idea. In addition to that, the Flash IDE modifies the code behind the scenes. That can lead to unexpected execution of code. A purely code based workflow sure is advantageous in this regard and recommended.

Comment: While trying to access a property that doesn't exist won't cause a compiler error, it should still cause a runtime error, even for dynamic objects. The trace statement would cause this

Comment: @Jezzamon no it doesn't, because the value of an undefined property of such an object is `undefined` and `undefined` is a valid value to be passed to the `trace` function. I added two short examples to my answer with the output they produce.

Comment: Hm. I guess I hadn't encountered that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @null That's it! 1 more problem that I had was the output of the score is 'NaN' and what causes that?

Comment: @John check for uninitialised variables and undefined math operations (division by 0)